# Problem with Custom Keyboard not applying color change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.androidauthority.com/lets-build-custom-keyboard-android-832362/) and created my own keyboard, but I can't change the background color for it's keys.

**keyboard.xml**

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="3px"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:keyHeight="60dp"
android:keyBackground="@color/color_green" 
android:keyTextColor="@color/color_red"
android:verticalGap="3px">
```

**keyboard_view.xml**

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/all_white">
</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```

**MyInputMethodService.java**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view, null);
    keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.number_pad);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return keyboardView;
}
```

[image]

I've tried change `android:keyBackground` and `android:keyTextColor`, but nothing changes, but if I change some key value in the same file it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and that `KeyboardView` is now deprecated (I'm playing around with it regardless though), but for anyone that comes across this in the future for any reason, here's a solution:

Set `keyTextColor` and `keyBackground` on `KeyboardView`, not on `Keyboard`.

Also, `keyBackground` needs to be an image, not a hex colour code.

Changing `KeyboardView` to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyTextColor="#FF0000"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">
</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```

You'll get something like:

[image]